# MacVim does not open new windows

Tags: vim, macvim

This happened right after I removed some folders on my system ruby, the more I have reinstalled the xcode. But even so, it opens new windows, only the icon appears and the toolbar of the software. I downloaded MacVim again and still continues without opening new windows ...

Grateful.

Comment: What did you remove from Ruby? That might be your problem (MacVim is compiled with Ruby support).

Comment: I was removing the ruby to reinstall it, because I was having trouble installing rails. I've installed xCode and nothing ... I'm having to use via terminal, plus my zencoding not work, I think I need to format the machine.

Comment: That might be best. It's not recommended to uninstall system Ruby; the typical scenario is that a developer just installs a newer version of Ruby -- either with RVM or rbenv or using a package manager or compiling from source and installing in /usr/local -- and uses that instead of the system Ruby.